# Android - Scrollable TextView with OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, textview

I have a scrollable textview with an onClickListener attached to it.

```
textView.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //DoStuff();
                }
            });
```

The problem is if I scroll the text, as soon as I lift my finger off the view it triggers the onClickListener.  The only way this doesn't happen is if I scroll and then move off the view before I lift my finger, and I can't exactly tell my users to do that :P

So my question is, is there a way to determine between a click and a scroll or is the only way to do this to use an onTouchListener and decide for myself if it was a scroll or a click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use onTouchListener and handle ON_DOWN and ON_MOVE instead of using onClick.